# Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку при Update-database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef

Ошибка:

> Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> CREATE TABLE [Posts] (
> [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
> [Title] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
> [Text] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
> [ImageUrl] nvarchar(255) NULL,
> [UserId] int NOT NULL,
> [PostStatisticsId] int NOT NULL,
> [TopicOfPostId] int NOT NULL,
> [CategoryId] int NOT NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_Posts] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
> CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_Categories_CategoryId] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_PostStatistics_PostStatisticsId] FOREIGN KEY ([PostStatisticsId]) REFERENCES [PostStatistics] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_TopicsOfPosts_TopicOfPostId] FOREIGN KEY ([TopicOfPostId]) REFERENCES [TopicsOfPosts] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_Users_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Posts_TopicsOfPosts_TopicOfPostId' on table 'Posts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Код:

```cs
using Forum_MVC.Data.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Title' field is required.")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Title must be between 3 and 100 characters.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Text' field is required.")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Image URL cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    public int PostStatisticsId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("PostStatisticsId")]
    public PostStatistics PostStatistics { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    
    public int TopicOfPostId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TopicOfPostId")]
    public TopicOfPost Topic { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Categories { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
using Forum_MVC.Data.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
public class TopicOfPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'Name' field is required.")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be between 3 and 100 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 255 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    // Active, Suspended
    public string VisibilityStatus { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы, скорее всего, используете MSSQL, а там, по-умолчанию, удаление является каскадным.

Что такое каскадное удаление? Это такая стратегия удаления, когда при удалении некоторой сущности автоматически удаляются все зависящие от неё сущности.

Как сказано во второй ошибке, проблема вашей схемы - наличие множественных каскадных путей. То есть, удалении некоторой сущности приведёт к удалению зависящей от неё сущности более одного раза. Некоторый СУБД такое допускают, MSSQL - нет.

В вашем конкретном примере проблема следующая. Если мы захотим удалить `User`-а, вслед за ним удалятся его `TopicOfPost`-ы и его `Post`-ы. Тут пока всё хорошо. НО! Удаление `TopicOfPost` приведёт к удалению всех зависящих от него `Post`-ов. Ой йо йой... Мы сущности типа `Post` уже удаляли, вот он и множественный каскадный путь.

Что делать? Всё зависит от того, что такое `TopicOfPost`.

- Если `TopicOfPost` это тема статьи, то я не понимаю почему одна тема может принадлежать нескольким статьям, и сущности стоит объединить.
- Если `TopicOfPost` это что-то по-типу категории, то я бы сделал ссылку на неё необязательной:

```
public int? TopicOfPostId { get; set; } // int? = IsRequired(false) = необязательная ссылка

[ForeignKey("TopicOfPostId")]
public TopicOfPost? Topic { get; set; }
```

- Если же ссылка должна быть обязательной, вы можете поменять каскадное удаление на `Restrict` или что-то другое (смотрите [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors))

И да, не используйте `[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]`, используйте вместо этого `nameof`: `[ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]`. Тогда статический анализ сможет выявить ошибку в имени, если вдруг такая возникнет.

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `[ForeignKey]` насколько я помню применяется к самому внешнему ключу, а вы применяете его к навигационному свойству,
попробуйте поменять вот так:

```
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Topic ))]
    public int TopicOfPostId { get; set; }
    public TopicOfPost Topic { get; set; }
```

И в таком же стиле сделать остальные подобные места

Так же желательно воспользоваться FluentAPI, для указания внешних ключей, так как он предоставляет большую функциональность, чем атрибуты

Comment: `[ForeignKey]` можно навешивать как навигационное свойство, так и на идентификатор. Как сказано в ошибке - проблема в наличии в схеме нескольких каскадных путей

Comment: прошу прощения за косяк, но вот FluentAPI всё таки должен помочь для разрешения таких ситуаций